# How can i apply Twitter Bootstrap theme to a website created using Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, orchardcms

I want to build a website using Orchard CMS ,also i want to use RWD (responsive web design) in
designing that website.
I want to use Twitter Bootstrap,but i don't have enough time for designing it from scratch,so  i want to apply a theme to the website, could anyone give me a guide for doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few existing Bootstrap-based themes out there. Eg. [this one](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Bootstrap) - just grab it and install from the admin Dashboard: